# Declare & format multiple labels for a form using for loop

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

NET developers.

I'm trying to put 20 labels on a form and place them line by line (I do this by the .Top method). I am sure there is a way I can program declaring and formatting by looping through more general code 20 times.

The below is what I've done for the first label.
Thanks in advance for help!

```
    Dim Label1 As New Label
    Me.Controls.Add(Label1)
    For m = 1 To OutlookManager3.GlobalVariables.SelectedAppointmentsNo
        With Label1
            .Width = 512
            .Height = 18
            .Top = subject.Top + subject.Height + m * 6 + (m - 1) * 18 + (m - 1) * 6
            .Left = 12
            .Text = "label" & m
        End With
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place this as the first line inside your loop:

```
Dim Label1 As New Label
```

And this as the last line insde your loop:

```
Me.Controls.Add(Label1)
```

**Example 1**

```
For m = 1 To OutlookManager3.GlobalVariables.SelectedAppointmentsNo
    Dim Label1 As New Label
    With Label1
        .Width = 512
        .Height = 18
        .Top = subject.Top + subject.Height + m * 6 + (m - 1) * 18 + (m - 1) * 6
        .Left = 12
        .Text = "label" & m
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(Label1)
Next
```

**Example 2**

```
For m = 1 To OutlookManager3.GlobalVariables.SelectedAppointmentsNo
    Me.Controls.Add(New Label() With {.Width = 512, .Height = 18, .Top = (subject.Top + subject.Height + m * 6 + (m - 1) * 18 + (m - 1) * 6), .Left = 12, .Text = ("label" & m)})
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use your code by place declare statement inside loop

For m = 1 To OutlookManager3.GlobalVariables.SelectedAppointmentsNo

```
Dim Label1 As New Label

With Label1

    .Width = 512

    .Height = 18

    .Top = subject.Top + subject.Height + m * 6 + (m - 1) * 18 + (m - 1) * 6

    .Left = 12

    .Text = "label" & m

End With

Me.Controls.Add(Label1)
```

Next

or use panel just like this but you have to place declare statement inside loop

or should make label array for future reference by

Dim label(yoursize) As Label
 For m = 1 To OutlookManager3.GlobalVariables.SelectedAppointmentsNo

```
label(m) = new label

label(m).ID="future referece id"

With Label1

    .Width = 512

    .Height = 18

    .Top = subject.Top + subject.Height + m * 6 + (m - 1) * 18 + (m - 1) * 6

    .Left = 12

    .Text = "label" & m

End With
```

by this you can use that next time
    Me.Controls.Add(Label1)
Next